# method to insert NA values based on a missing category

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
  Author   Score   Value
  A        High    10
  B        Low     20
  C        Medium  30
  A        Low     15
  B        Medium  22
```

I'd like to rearrange the data frame to display that an Author has no score in one of the possible 'Score'.

I would like to insert an entry for an author so that a `NA` would appear.

```
  Author   Score   Value
  A        Low     15
  A        Medium  NA
  A        High    10
  B        Low     20
  B        Medium  22
  B        High    NA
  C        Low     NA
  C        Medium  30
  C        High    NA
```

Is there an easy way i.e. a command to do that in `R` or should I better write a dedicated function?

Any suggestion about which command or any tips to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: actually this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591748/r-adding-nas-into-data-frame/26592023#26592023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `expand.grid` and `merge`. Here's what you do.

```
lvls <- expand.grid(lapply(df[, c('Author', 'Score')], levels))
merge(df, lvls, all=TRUE)
```

Or if the order is important, you can do

```
lvls <- expand.grid(lapply(df[, c('Author', 'Score')], levels))
df.new <- merge(df, lvls, all=TRUE)
df.new[, 'Score'] <- factor(df.new[, 'Score'], levels=c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'))
df.new[order(df.new$Author, df.new$Score), ]
```

In case your `data.frame` doesn't have `factors`, but has `characters`, you can also use the following more general function. You'll still have to reorder afterwards.

```
expand.df <- function(data, factors) {
  lvls <- expand.grid(lapply(data[, factors], function(x) {
    if (is.factor(x)) return(levels(x))
    else return(unique(x))
  }))
  return(merge(df, lvls, all=TRUE))
}
expand.df(df, c('Author', 'Score'))
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff! It does exactly what I was aiming. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df$Score <- factor(df$Score, levels=c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'))
setkey(setDT(df), Author, Score)[CJ(unique(Author), unique(Score))]
#   Author  Score Value
#1:      A    Low    15
#2:      A Medium    NA
#3:      A   High    10
#4:      B    Low    20
#5:      B Medium    22
#6:      B   High    NA
#7:      C    Low    NA
#8:      C Medium    30
#9:      C   High    NA
```

Comment: Very nice. I think it makes a lot of sense to compute the `unique` values internally. i.e., whether `CJ(Author, Score)` should be sufficient to return unique combinations automatically.

Comment: @Arun Ohh ok.  I misunderstood, sorry.  Yes, it makes sense.